# Video Gravity in CALayer in AVExportSession

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, video, swift3

My app first record a video then  after adding some effects it exports output using AVExportSession.

First, the problem was video gravity during video recording which was solved by changing `videoGravity` property inside `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill`.

Second, the problem was with showing the video which was recorded which was solved by changing the `VideoGravity` property inside `AVPlayerLayer` to `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill`

but, the problem is now when i want to export video after adding some effect by using `AVExportSession`, there is some video gravity issues again. even changing the `contentsGravity` property in CALayer doesn't affect the output. i should mention that this problem is obvious in iPad.

here is the image when i want to show the video before adding some effects :[image]

as you can see the tip of my finger is at top of screen (because i have fixed the issue with the gravity in the layer inside the app)

but after exporting and saving to gallery what i see is like this :[image]

i know that the problem is with the gravity but i don't know how i can fix it. i don't know if any changes i should make to video when i'm recording or change in the code below when i'm exporting :

```
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoUrl, options: nil)

    let tracks =  asset.tracks(withMediaType : AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let videoTrack:AVAssetTrack = tracks[0] as AVAssetTrack
    let timerange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration)

    let viewSize = parentView.bounds.size
    let trackSize = videoTrack.naturalSize

    let compositionVideoTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

    do {
        try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(timerange, of: videoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    let compositionAudioTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

    for audioTrack in asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio) {
        do {
            try compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(audioTrack.timeRange, of: audioTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    let videolayer = CALayer()
    videolayer.frame.size = viewSize
    videolayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill

    let parentlayer = CALayer()
    parentlayer.frame.size = viewSize
    parentlayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill

    parentlayer.addSublayer(videolayer)

    let layercomposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    layercomposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
    layercomposition.renderSize = viewSize
    layercomposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videolayer, in: parentlayer)

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration)

    let videotrack = composition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as AVAssetTrack
    let layerinstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videotrack)

    let trackTransform = videoTrack.preferredTransform
    let xScale = viewSize.height / trackSize.width
    let yScale = viewSize.width / trackSize.height

    var exportTransform : CGAffineTransform!
    if (getVideoOrientation(transform: videoTrack.preferredTransform).1 == .up) {
        exportTransform = videoTrack.preferredTransform.translatedBy(x: trackTransform.ty * -1 , y: 0).scaledBy(x: xScale , y: yScale)
    } else {
        exportTransform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: viewSize.width, y: 0).rotated(by: .pi/2).scaledBy(x: xScale, y: yScale)
    }

    layerinstruction.setTransform(exportTransform, at: kCMTimeZero)

    instruction.layerInstructions = [layerinstruction]
    layercomposition.instructions = [instruction]

    let filePath = FileHelper.getVideoTimeStampName()
    let exportedUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

    guard let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {delegate?.exportFinished(status: .failed, outputUrl: exportedUrl); return}

    assetExport.videoComposition = layercomposition
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    assetExport.outputURL = exportedUrl
    assetExport.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        switch assetExport.status {
        case .completed:
            print("video exported successfully")
            self.delegate?.exportFinished(status: .completed, outputUrl: exportedUrl)
            break
        case .failed:
            self.delegate?.exportFinished(status: .failed, outputUrl: exportedUrl)
            print("exporting video failed: \(String(describing: assetExport.error))")
            break
        default :
            print("the video export status is \(assetExport.status)")
            self.delegate?.exportFinished(status: assetExport.status, outputUrl: exportedUrl)
            break
        }
    })
```

i would appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` the video capture screen will adjust itself to the `CALayer`. So what really happening is that the camera is actually capturing the second image you provided. You can resolve this issue by these steps:

1. Get the image as a UIImage
2. Crop the image with the same CALayer size you are using
3. Upload the cropped image to server, show it to the user etc.

For cropping the image you can use this :

```
extension UIImage {
    func crop(to:CGSize) -> UIImage {
            guard let cgimage = self.cgImage else { return self }

            let contextImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimage)

            let contextSize: CGSize = contextImage.size

            //Set to square
            var posX: CGFloat = 0.0
            var posY: CGFloat = 0.0
            let cropAspect: CGFloat = to.width / to.height

            var cropWidth: CGFloat = to.width
            var cropHeight: CGFloat = to.height

            if to.width > to.height { //Landscape
                cropWidth = contextSize.width
                cropHeight = contextSize.width / cropAspect
                posY = (contextSize.height - cropHeight) / 2
            } else if to.width < to.height { //Portrait
                cropHeight = contextSize.height
                cropWidth = contextSize.height * cropAspect
                posX = (contextSize.width - cropWidth) / 2
            } else { //Square
                if contextSize.width >= contextSize.height { //Square on landscape (or square)
                    cropHeight = contextSize.height
                    cropWidth = contextSize.height * cropAspect
                    posX = (contextSize.width - cropWidth) / 2
                }else{ //Square on portrait
                    cropWidth = contextSize.width
                    cropHeight = contextSize.width / cropAspect
                    posY = (contextSize.height - cropHeight) / 2
                }
            }

            let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: cropWidth, height: cropHeight)
            // Create bitmap image from context using the rect
            let imageRef: CGImage = contextImage.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)!

            // Create a new image based on the imageRef and rotate back to the original orientation
            let cropped: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(to, true, self.scale)
            cropped.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: to.width, height: to.height))
            let resized = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            return resized!
        }
}
```